# Run function only once for particular element

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple todo app and I am new in JavaScript and I am stuck in a problem.

I am trying to run function only once for a particular element ID. like,

There are 5 `divs` with `IDs` `1,2,3,4,5`. so I am accessing them by `className` and then their ID.

Then I am storing their id in a variable and storing it to prevent the function from running with the previous id.

page.html

```js
function myFunction() {

    // Used for getting last element of all the classes
    var element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".fields")).pop();

    var previousId = element.id;

    var executed = false
    if (previousId === element.id) {
         if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            console.log("Run only once");
            console.log(previousId);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="1" oninput="myFunction(id)" class="fields">

<input type="text" id="2" class="fields">
```

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to run the function only once for the current input field user is typing in.

I tried removing `if (previousId === element.id) {` and running only `if(!executed){` but it also didn't worked.

But Whenever I type in input field then it executing every time I press the key.

I have tried many times but it is still not working. Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: `previousId === element.id` currently is always true.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I tried removing `if (previousId === element.id) {` and running only `if(!executed){` but it also didn't worked.

Comment: could you use `onchange` instead of `oninput`?

Comment: FYI you could store that information inside the element itself using `getAttribute/setAttribute('data-nameofyourparam')` and you would make your life much simpler

Comment: @DiegoDeVita, I will read this comment, Whenever  I my life is hard

Comment: Or instead of having a dedicated array as you were suggested you simply had to set the attribute on the element you processed already and it was much better IMO. But it’s up to you to learn things and adopt solutions accordingly. That solution is good enough. I hope my advice was helpful anyway. Your elements may not have an id set in a wider scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save an array of already runned id and chek it

```js
let alreadyRunned = []

function myFunction(id) {
  if (alreadyRunned.includes(id)) {
    return;
  }
  alreadyRunned = [...alreadyRunned, id]
  console.log("Run only once");
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="1" oninput="myFunction(1)" class="fields">

<input type="text" id="2" class="fields" oninput="myFunction(2)">
```